# Battery Boost?Drain?

Tags: updates, battery-life

I recently updated my Note 2 to 4.3 and it has been working quite well. But today in the train I was using it and the battery level drained to 20%, Since the battery was low, I switched it off and came home. When I put it on charge and turned it on- the battery level said 67%. How come it got such a boost? When I took it to work today, it had only about 56% 
and I come home with 20 and all of a sudden its 67%
How?

Comment: Are you rooted? It may be down to the battery being incorrectly calibrated.

Answer (score -1):

This is  a sign that you overuse your battery,frequently leaving your apps on....your battery is damaged and might need to be replaced...but till you can do that...you can always:
1.avoid charging overnight 
2.use the correct charger
3.if you aren't using your data or wifi turn it off,to preserve battery life

Comment: Oh. That would mean all my batteries must be long dead, and a ghost is working my devices: I 1) always charge them overnight, 2) rarely use the original charger (but simply take what's on-hand), and 3) never care about turning data off (except for "silent hours", where I send my devices to airplane mode). Also: How do you turn your apps off? Never heard about such requirements, sorry. That leaves a possible faulty battery, which I agree might be the cause.

Comment: you can use clean master to monitor all your apps and know the various apps consuming battery with du battery

Comment: Yes, that's true. The stock settings also offer you means to find "big consumers". But that doesn't answer the question. OP is asking for an explanation of those "percentage jumps", not which app consumed how much battery. I've also never heard of "battery overusage", or that high load causes the described symptoms. No offense meant, but only "your battery might be damaged and need a replacement" could count as a partly answer to the question, and as *assumption* would better be a comment. Of course, that's only my opinion (unless upvoted ;)